# How to fix Undefined index notice in contribution_date_relative?

Tags: smartgroups, issues

When I try to **Update Smart Group Counts** in Manage Groups, the CiviCRM provides me with numerous notices.

What is wrong and where do I fix that?

```
Notice: Undefined index: contribution_date_relative in CRM_Contact_Form_Search_Custom_ContributionAggregate->where() (line 204 of /crm/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Contact/Form/Search/Custom/ContributionAggregate.php).
Notice: Undefined index: contribution_date_low in CRM_Contact_Form_Search_Custom_ContributionAggregate->where() (line 205 of /crm/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Contact/Form/Search/Custom/ContributionAggregate.php).
Notice: Undefined index: contribution_date_high in CRM_Contact_Form_Search_Custom_ContributionAggregate->where() (line 206 of /crm/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Contact/Form/Search/Custom/ContributionAggregate.php).
Notice: Undefined index: contribution_date_relative in CRM_Contact_Form_Search_Custom_ContributionAggregate->where() (line 204 of /crm/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Contact/Form/Search/Custom/ContributionAggregate.php).
Notice: Undefined index: contribution_date_low in CRM_Contact_Form_Search_Custom_ContributionAggregate->where() (line 205 of /crm/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Contact/Form/Search/Custom/ContributionAggregate.php).
Notice: Undefined index: contribution_date_high in CRM_Contact_Form_Search_Custom_ContributionAggregate->where() (line 206 of /crm/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Contact/Form/Search/Custom/ContributionAggregate.php).
Notice: Undefined index: contribution_date_relative in CRM_Contact_Form_Search_Custom_ContributionAggregate->where() (line 204 of /crm/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Contact/Form/Search/Custom/ContributionAggregate.php).
Notice: Undefined index: contribution_date_low in CRM_Contact_Form_Search_Custom_ContributionAggregate->where() (line 205 of /crm/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Contact/Form/Search/Custom/ContributionAggregate.php).
Notice: Undefined index: contribution_date_high in CRM_Contact_Form_Search_Custom_ContributionAggregate->where() (line 206 of /crm/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Contact/Form/Search/Custom/ContributionAggregate.php).
Notice: Undefined index: contribution_date_relative in CRM_Contact_Form_Search_Custom_ContributionAggregate->where() (line 204 of /crm/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Contact/Form/Search/Custom/ContributionAggregate.php).
Notice: Undefined index: contribution_date_low in CRM_Contact_Form_Search_Custom_ContributionAggregate->where() (line 205 of /crm/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Contact/Form/Search/Custom/ContributionAggregate.php).
Notice: Undefined index: contribution_date_high in CRM_Contact_Form_Search_Custom_ContributionAggregate->where() (line 206 of /crm/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Contact/Form/Search/Custom/ContributionAggregate.php).
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aivars,

Have logged an issue for this in CiviCRM [here](https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/issues/837) and submitted a [PR](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/13921) for this fix. Can you please test by applying patch from [here](https://patch-diff.githubusercontent.com/raw/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/13921.patch)? If it works for you than please add a comment on PR which will help to get this fix in core and have it available in next release.

Cheers

Pradeep

Comment: Indeed, the notices have disappeared with this patch.

Answer (score 0):

Those are php notices. It looks like you are running drupal so see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/6363323/8332458